# Displaying values in the y axis of a linechart from javafx FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml, linechart

I am using the scene builder to build the GUI of an application and it works fine when a I pass the data to the XYChart.Series, however, I need to display double values to the forth and fifth decimal place in the y axis as it is live data from the EUR/US and instead the data is displayed to the second decimal place here is a piece of my code

```
@FXML
private LineChart<?,?> grafica;

for(int count = 0; count < dataArray.size(); count++)
    {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(count, 
                dataArray.get(count)));
    }

    grafica.getData().add(series);
```

I though first that the chart was going to display according to the data but I realise this was no the case. I try to instantiate the variable grafica to pass arguments like variables type Numberaxis with a defined lower and upper bound to the constructor LineChart but as soon as I do that that the chart no longer display the data. So is it possible to change how the data is displayed in the y axis or the axis in general with fxml?

Comment: Can you show the relevant FXML? I think what you need is to set a `tickLabelFormatter` on the y-axis.